# Static rendering server for markdown and code files

Tags: python, server, frontend, repository, rendering

When provided with an archive of a code repository (assuming the repository contains code files, and markdown files with possibly links towards other .md files) with or without a .git file.

Is there an easy to setup way to serve the code locally to provide an interface ala github permitting to have a minima:

- proper formatting of markdown files
- easy navigation between files (being able to click on markdown links and to navigate between the different folders easily)
- possibly code linting as well(python files) ?

Executing:

```bash
python -m http.server 8080
```

At the root of the repository is a start but it looks ugly and when clicking on markdown files it downloads them instead of displaying them.

Disclaimer: I have close to 0 knowledge of frontends' behinds the scenes.

Comment: maybe with something like `docker run gitlab/gitlab-ce [+ mount and port params]`?

Comment: Will try ! For now the python package `static-markdown` goes a long way into doing what I want but it display only markdown files and not other code files.